# Using Html5 Notification in Blackberry Webworks

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I am using HTML5 Local Notifications in Blackberry 10 (Higher Version BB z10) using webworks 1.0

And it works fine for Me.

The code used look like this.

```
    var n = new Notification("MyMessage", {
            'body' : content.message,
            'tag': content.chatid,
            'target' : "MyMessage",
            'targetAction' : "bb.action.OPEN"

            });
```

The link of this api reference is here

[Blackberry Webworks Notification](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/gold/notification.html)

Now there is one more field as  ""

> payload: Payload to send to the invoked app. Data must be Base64 encoded. Value is passed on to the Invocation Framework as data.

This to open a specific html page based on the notification you click.

I am not able to use it correctly. Also blackberry support forms do not give reply or any sample for this.

[Question I asked in Blackberry Support Forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Using-Notification-In-BB-Z10/td-p/2796751)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a simpler way of achieving what you are trying to do.
First of all allow me to point you to the notification sample:
https://github.com/blackberry/BB10-WebWorks-Samples/blob/master/notify/.

To answer your specific query you need to bear in mind 2 things in the following order:

(1). The app needs to be invokable so you need to modify the config.xml and the index.html respectively:

**config.xml**

```
<rim:invoke-target id="com.myApp.entrypoint">
    <type>APPLICATION</type>
    <filter>
        <action>bb.action.OPEN</action>
        <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
    </filter>
</rim:invoke-target>
```

where "id" is your unique ID (ie. nobody else should be using that)

**index.html or index.js**

```
document.addEventListener("invoked", onInvoked, false);
```

add the above after the system has fired the "deviceready" event.
The "onInvoked" function will look like:

```
function onInvoked(data) {
   var pageToOpen = data.URI;
   //do something with pageToOpen now
}
```

(2). Your notification will need to have the attribute "payLoadURI" set to the html page that you want to open. I'm thinking It will be something like

```
local:///myPage.html
```

This "myPage.html" it's what your "pageToOpen" variable will receive and at that stage you can push the right HTML fragment to the top.

I hope it helps.

P.S. this has been tested with **WebWorks 2.0** so I would advise you to upgrade for a better experience.